# How to rewrite the output of $content inside a pane template?

Tags: 7, theming, panels

I am trying to reformat / rewrite the output of pane content inside my panel template.

Here is what I have:

```
panels-pane--panels-mini--some-name.tpl
```

Inside this file I have:

```
print render($content)
```

I need to break apart the items inside of content. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your panels module the function template_preprocess_panels_pane() you can use this.

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21panels%21panels.module/function/template_preprocess_panels_pane/7

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!panels!panels.module/function/template_preprocess_panels_pane/8